# How to add the nth term on last div

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

i am attempting to add an nth term on the last div. i dont want any right margin on the last div and for all the boxes to float inline when the screen width is decreased.

have added a fiddle so you can show your working,

http://jsfiddle.net/7Yg5X/

Any help would be grand!

```
.wrap{
        width:100%;
        border:1px solid black;
        float:left;
}
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:black;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;

}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Yg5X/

Comment: `.box:last-child { margin-right: 0px; }` ?

Comment: If it has to work in IE8 and below, you have an exception to the rule, and can add an inline style to the last element.

Comment: @adeneo Better add a class that'll be styled that way: `<div class="box box-last"><!-- content --></div>`

Comment: it needs to be responsive though??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `.box:nth-child(n){margin-right:0;}`. Here (n) will be the box number for which you don't want to use margin.

Comment: For responsiveness you have to use more css. See this http://jsfiddle.net/7Yg5X/4/